# += behavior when adding numpy array to scalar in python

Tags: python, numpy

I have a scalar variable and want to add a numpy array. I was a bit sloppy and programmed it as follows

```
import numpy as np
x = 5
x += np.ones(5)
print(x)
```

This code indeed produces `[6. 6. 6. 6. 6.]`, but in hindsight I don't understand why. After all, I thought that `+=` does not create a new location for `x` in memory, but simply adds values to the same location in memory. But what I added (an array of  length 5) needs a lot larger location in memory. So why does this work? Should it work? Is it save?

Comment: Thank you for that reference. I have been using numpy arrays for years and I don't think the answer is obvious. What I could find in the tutorial is: "Python requires “a+=1” to be equivalent to “a = a + 1”". Which means, to me, that Python does create a new variable. While numpy does something different: use the same location in memory. Is that what is happening?

Comment: `+=` modifies the variable in-place if it is mutable, e.g a numpy array.  But `x` is a integer, immutable.  So it's replaced.

Comment: Thanks, hpaulj. I suspected that. Sounds like a good rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a scalar:

```
In [128]: x = 23.2                                                                                     
In [129]: id(x)                                                                                        
Out[129]: 140067097316640
In [130]: x += 12                                                                                      
In [131]: x                                                                                            
Out[131]: 35.2
In [132]: id(x)                                                                                        
Out[132]: 140067097315080
```

the += has assigned a new number to the variable.

For an array:

```
In [133]: x = np.ones(3)                                                                               
In [134]: x                                                                                            
Out[134]: array([1., 1., 1.])
In [135]: id(x)                                                                                        
Out[135]: 140067132298464
In [136]: x.__array_interface__['data']                                                                
Out[136]: (140067416761584, False)
In [137]: x += 12                                                                                      
In [138]: id(x)                                                                                        
Out[138]: 140067132298464
In [139]: x.__array_interface__['data']                                                                
Out[139]: (140067416761584, False)
In [140]: x                                                                                            
Out[140]: array([13., 13., 13.])
```

adding changes the values, but not the array object (id) or even its databuffer.  The action is all in-place.

For a list, `+=` can change an element of the list, without changing the rest of the list:

```
In [141]: x = [1,2,3]                                                                                  
In [142]: x[1] +=12                                                                                    
In [143]: x                                                                                            
Out[143]: [1, 14, 3]
```

So for Python scalars the `i += 1` notation is a syntactic short cut, but doesn't change the calculation (but it would be good to look at the generated bytecode).

However, as pointed out in the `np.ufunc.at` docs,

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html#numpy.ufunc.at

, the array `+=` action is buffered.  The `x+=12` is actually `x[:] = x+12`.

Answer (score 0):

`__iadd__()` is not implemented for `int` type so it fall back to `x = x + np.ones(5)`

> For instance, if x is an instance of a class with an **iadd**() method, x += y is equivalent to x = x.__iadd__(y) . Otherwise, x.__add__(y) and y.__radd__(x) are considered, as with the evaluation of x + y.

[documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__iadd__#object.__iadd__)